# TV Movie from the '80s (maybe early '90s) about someone who gets superpowers but loses them in the dark

Tags: story-identification, tv

I specifically recall watching this TV movie when I was a kid ('80s or early '90s) where this guy gets powers. Someone(?) is trying to figure out the extent of his powers and puts something (perhaps a petri dish with his cells?) in a refrigerator, and figures out that it isn't the cold that slows him, but the darkness. Can anyone remember the name of this TV movie?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. What sort of powers did the main character get?

Comment: I wonder if it might be "Northstar" from 1986. He got superpowers in the light, and lost them in the dark. I don't remember them putting his cells in a fridge though

Comment: Out of interest for Northstar found this; "In this sci-fi film an astronaut finds himself endowed with superhuman powers after he was exposed to severe radiation resulting from a solar disturbance during the time he was in space. He uses those powers to find the one who murdered his colleague." Ring any bells?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At a guess, this sounds a bit like "I-Man", which was a Disney movie (part of The Magic World of Disney) from 1986.
From IMDB summary:

> When a man is exposed to an alien gas, he acquires the ability to heal instantly and survive any injury or toxin.

At one point (after crashing a truck into the ocean to avert an explosion or other disaster), the rescue team comments "No one could survive the cold there", a person who knows the main character remarks "It isn't the cold that will kill him, it's the dark" (or words to that effect).